Why isn't all genetics work published on GitHub?
Update: When hackernews is ruthlessly critical of a new software project, the implicit assumption is that software projects are dime-at-dozen, attention of HN users is worth millions of dollars, hence criticism protects this attention from being wasted. Genetics doesn't yet seem to have the same problems or same solutions. I should have more empathy for that.
I don't mean to attack any person specifically, just ideas and processes of how to do things.

I'm coming more from a software background than a genetics one so forgive my ignorance but:
Why isn't GitHub the default place to publish work in genetics?
Just to give an example, I was looking at pairwise alignment between genomes: https://asia.ensembl.org/info/genome/compara/analyses.html
Here's a list of stats that's been obtained. https://asia.ensembl.org/info/genome/compara/mlss.html?mlss=1098
Why isn't there a list of commands (presumably lastz called with some options) to generate these stats?
Why does lastz release source code but not compiled releases? https://github.com/lastz/lastz/releases
Why does clicking on details open an online GUI browser for the entire genome instead of ... some actual commands I could run on my machine? https://asia.ensembl.org/Pan_troglodytes/Location/Compara_Alignments/Image?align=1098;r=14:80237279-80308917
And if something as important as aligning genomes is like this, I'm assuming more niche work requires even more hassle if you want replicate results or play around with it.
Publishing work to GitHub has lot of obvious benefits:

replication of results is trivial - just clone repo and run command
high signal-to-noise ratio - related to previous point, you can't hide behind bad results when replicating results is trivial
code quality - you can identify who is actually a good developer by looking at their code, and which repos and tools are good quality, so it is safe to build on top of them
docs and activity - relatedly, you can also instantly identify which tools have good docs and which tools have active developers, so you can avoid the tools that are poorly documented or inactive
no gatekeeping - anybody can push code to GitHub, you don't need a degree. more people can contribute (while still keeping signal-to-noise ratio high)
high-level abstraction - you can build high-level abstractions, break down a problem into multiple pieces and different research fields work on them in parallel. (People writing OS and hardware stuff, network engineers, web developers, sysadmins can all build on top of each other's work without having expertise in each others' fields)

Some blockers I can imagine are:

Not all genetics experts are trained to code well - Sure, but like, doesn't getting good at coding help you become a genetics expert in the first place? How do you generate results quickly or verify others results if you can't code well yourself? And how do you become an expert in genetics if you can't do either of those things fast?
Lack of data standards - I don't know enough about this to comment. FASTA, BLAST6, etc seem standardised but there is a lot of metadata about various genes written in plain English, I'm not sure if there's a standardised format for that yet.
Some steps are subjective or matter of taste - Data cleaning and preprocessing seems quite involved for genetic data. More so than say, most NLP work in ML. I understand this makes it more work, but I'm unsure why that means it isn't worth doing. I understand some decisions in data cleaning or labelling can be subjective and a matter of research taste.

(Although I'm vaguely suspicious of this reasoning too, research taste just means we don't have proper reasoning for the best way of doing something yet. Being able to run code means we can develop benchmarks on all such steps and get hard empirical data)



I don't mean to rant here btw. I'm not a particular good software developer either. (Guess how I know? Because I've seen what actually good looks like, and hence I can benchmark my own abilities against others better. That's what open source allows you to do.)
I'm just curious why open source culture of pushing everything to github rather than arxiv, hasn't penetrated genetics research yet.

Update: Looks like lack of data standards is a major problem in the field.

Update: I just started going through biopython documentation and ... why does it read like a novel? :/ :/ :/ Why are the docs teaching me python indexes from zero? Why is there a random anecdote in the middle of the docs about how previous software version had a bug?  Why are the docs full of exclamation marks and "this is not too scary" comments (presumably for people who are scared of writing software?)

scikit-bio docs are so much better. But not enough algorithms implemented I think? Are they hoping other people will build on top of scikit-bio in future?

This doesn't really address most of your points, but GitHub is not an archive tool (it requires using a secondary tool to properly archive)

@Darlingtonia I mean fair but like, why does this matter? In machine learning, people know the real work happens on GitHub but publish papers just for namesake. I would be surprised if anyone is rejecting actually useful papers because their citation is not in Zenodo or whatever.

Why should it be on Github? You will not work on a genome or fork it. There are repositories for the genome data (Ensembl and NCBI) where you can get the data to work with it.

@Chris Yeah it's fine for the data to be on Ensembl or NCBI and the code to be on GitHub.

Certainly getting buy-in for researchers to post their code and data is an ongoing push, so I'm not speaking to the generalized question, but have you not been able to find what you need in the Ensembl GitHub organization or using their API?

@Darlingtonia They have linked to lastz which requires me to compile it from source, figure out what arguments they have called lastz with, and that will probably still only give some of the stats. Maybe there is some repo they've published it in (I don't know), but they've not linked it from the comparative genomics page that generates the results.

I don't actually need this specific result, I'm just curious why isn't it as simple as git clone somelink.git; run app

@Darlingtonia Their API mentions comparative genomics, but this link has class definitions and nothing human-readable. The API you've linked mention doxygen, which they've deprecated in favour of ensembl-hive, and again, not sure where I'm supposed to start.

There's a manual for hive, if that's the tool you want. However, I'd recommend surveying the many tools and FAQ for what might best fit your needs. To my eye, Ensembl has gone to great lengths to embody open source culture, and not only made raw code available, but produced several complex tools catering to technical users who aren't necessarily software engineers (or are just tired of trying to compile lastz on their bespoke computing cluster).

@Darlingtonia Sorry if this comes across as arrogant but like, I will literally pay non-trivial sum of money if someone can use Ensembl API and no outside help (such as contacting Ensembl team members) to replicate all the stats on this page within a week. Ideal world would allow you to replicate it within an hour.

I know I'm coming across the wrong way on this, maybe I should log off and return tomorrow, I'm sorry.

As to why Lastz and many others provide source code rather than compiled is that lots of people use *nix variants of some sort (including Mac) so they would need to provide compiled packages for all the variants and the source code for the variants they don't want to compile for.  In addition not everyone runs the most up to date software, many groups will be using a particular version of software with a particular set of programs for their own purposes, so you would need to provide all those too... Source is easier.

@bob1 This makes sense but like, popular tools can release pre-compiled for multiple *nix variants. (Atleast in the software world) Or they provide the compiled release for 2-3 popular OSes and some lengthy instructions for how to compile it yourself for other OS. Maybe these programs are not as popular?

@ghosts_in_the_code Sure, they could, but the reality is that often these tools are maintained by a research group that maybe has only one or two programmers on it and little time/money to do so, so it just doesn't happen.

To amplify what @bob1 has already written: most of the work in genomics is done by grad students and post-docs. Having those folks spend time on building anything like multi-platform installers is doing them a grave disservice. They are supposed to be working on extending our knowledge of science and/or coming up with novel algorithms. Doing commercial style software engineering is not what they signed up for. Funding agencies generally don't give two figs for providing niceties like installers and will look at you funny if you ask for funding for it*.

*They will sometimes in special cases fund for improved usability, but not often. Frankly the largest problem in bioinformatics is not the lack of binary distributions, it's the prevalence of  'ghost software'. Some grad student writes a useful program with a novel algorithm, it develops a small user base, the grad student graduates and moves on to a different topic, bit rot sets in, and after 2-3 years the software stops working.

I've edited out the personal commentary as it's not allowed network-wide, but the sentiment of the OP's update is appreciated and understood.

In addition to not being peer-reviewed, GitHub is commercial and not archival: see for example Zenodo: https://zenodo.org/search?q=genetics&l=list&p=1&s=10&sort=bestmatch

A trivial answer for much (most?) genetics work: it is not computationally reproducible, no code was written, and no CLI commands were run. Data analysis is restricted to excel spreadsheets and raw digital imaging. In some cases, no computers at all are involved.
Consider Lee Hartwell's beautiful classic work elucidating cell cycle control that won him the Nobel Prize. His tools were yeast culture equipment, a microscope, and a camera.

Thanks for taking time to reply! I just read the paper.

P.S. I have understood the problem in genetics completely wrong. I thought the main problem in genetics is that there's a ton of data available and what's needed is for people to find insights from it more quickly. For this, being good at software will help. But now I'm realising that even though the raw data can be obtained cheaply (DNA sequencing, protein sequencing, measuring protein expression level, digital imaging of cell phenotype, etc.), it takes lot of research labour to go from DNA to protein to phenotype. So automating this research labour may be the best way to accelerate the field

I would love to get any comment from your side. And I apologise again for how I behaved earlier.

I'd say that the problem of having a well-developed research question (e.g. "why are some cats grey and other cats orange?" vs. "i want to sequence a cat genome!") is the big hurdle for highly automated science. In the absence of such a question you can spend a ton of money and effort on something rather uninteresting. That's probably the biggest factor in your research labor- people actually planning out experiments that will answer those specific questions. There's a middle ground for big resource projects like databases or methods development, but those still need compelling applications.

Oh yes! What you're saying makes sense. Maybe I'll try asking this. Suppose you were made in charge of all biotech research on Earth. Suppose right now you can ask researchers to run 1,000 bacterial gene cloning experiments per month. Suppose automation made it possible to run 1,000,000 bacterial gene cloning experiments per month instead of 1,000. When picking which 1,000,000 to run, would you be particular about running certain types of experiments (based on the hypothesis you want to investigate) or would you rather just randomly pick lots of species and lots of genes and mutations?

The potential mutational space of biodiversity is astronomically large. 1,000,000 is a very small number if randomly distributed across biodiversity and mutation types. The mutational space with a meaningful effect is a pretty small subsample of that, though still astronomically large. You'd be wasting your effort if you didn't focus on interesting well-posed questions.

Thank you your answer is super helpful

Github isn't a publishing site for any science at all that I am aware of, it lacks the key component of peer-review. ArXiv isn't either, it's for preprints and also lacks peer review.
For many geneticists they use a collection of tools from various coders to do their work, not develop whole new tools each time. It's incredibly inefficient to write whole new tools when someone else already has the tool that does the job you want it to do. I'm aware that this isn't the case in most software development because of commercial sensitivity and copyright issues, but science is all about sharing data openly so the most popular tools are FOSS (Free Open Source Software).
So, geneticists generally gather the tools into a pipeline of sorts and use that to process the data. Many of these tools ARE on Github (e.g. here's TopHat among many others). Details of the pipeline are published in the papers written or hosted on Github (e.g. this one) or some other location like a locally hosted webpage for the lab as specified in the publication.
A popular tool for geneticists is the programming language Python - particularly Bioconda (note where that link takes you..). Have a look at the repository of packages within Bioconda, then choose a random one and look at where its homepage is...

Thanks for replying. 1. Yup Tophat/Hisat2 seems good, I haven't run it but just from reading. 2. Thanks for the bioconda link. Okay you're right there's more code being written than I thought at first. After seeing all the repos I think I'm better understanding what the problem actually is. I guess I'll spend more time on it myself. 3. I'm comparing to FOSS work in software in general, most commercial work builds on top of FOSS too. As far as I can see there is way more tools-building-on-top-of-each-other in software world compared to genetics.


Is peer review that important? I'm honestly unsure. Status and reputation in open source tech circles depends on other people building on top of your work. Which is in a way similar to paper citations. Ultimately though you want to solve some real problem for a real person (maybe detect cancer or something) and that person will provide you feedback as to whether your solution works for them or not. Status/reputation/etc are just incentives to get people to do the intermediate steps of work before you're solving the real problem. (Atleast that's my understanding of it)


@ghosts_in_the_code People publishing in genetics are not "in open source tech circles", they're in genetics. You're not stumbling on something new, biologists are quite aware of issues with reproducibility and code availability in the field. However, you're coming across as extremely rude about it. Like someone from "fork culture" showing up in a country where people use chopsticks and blasting them for not using forks.

@ghosts_in_the_code Maybe you learn something about the field first, before you try to re-invent the wheel and understand how things work. This includes things like peer review. Also: A lot of biology research is not about solving problems, it is about understanding things. That is how science works. When you understand how things work or how they are connected, you can start solving problems. However, this is often a complicated task.

@ghosts_in_the_code Peer review is the foundation of science. It provides a critical check and balance system, where the work must hold up to independent scrutiny before being published. During the Covid pandemic, much of this process was suspended due to the need to disseminate information as fast as possible and resulted in a lot of misinformation being spread. e.g. the use of ivermectin as treatment (it doesn't work...), which would have been pulled up by peer review. Publishing quality work in high quality journals is how your research reputation grows - none of that without peer review!

@bob1 Oh this makes sense actually. (the ivermectin example) Usually the worst that happens with bad software is wasting other people's time before they eventually realise it. But here one of the bad outcomes is people consume the wrong medicines and suffer health effects. So you can't wait till the bad outcome actually happens, for people to realise the solution is wrong. I really wish there was like a fully automated genetic engineering lab for bacteria or something, so people could iterate quickly without the downsides.

@Chris Yes fair, I could spend more time trying to understand stuff

@BryanKrause You are right. Apologies for coming across as rude. I don't mean to attack anyone specific. It's more of "Santa Claus is not real" type of frustration for me. But I'm sorry I should learn to express myself better.
